# select category-variable with highest value across multiple samples

Tags: r

For each samples (D1, D2 and D3) I would like to find the highest expressed species "`s__`" within each genus "`g__`". For instance within the genus Acinetobacter, there are three species and I would like to find which one has the highest values in D1, D2, and D3. 
Any idea how to approach this?

in

```
                                                D1     D2    D3
g__Acinetobacter|s__Acinetobacter_pittii        12     21    424
g__Acinetobacter|s__Acinetobacter_oleivorans    4      4     23
g__Acinetobacter|s__Acinetobacter_larvae        1      53    232
g__Pseudomonas|s__Pseudomonas_aeruginosa        13     13    323
g__Pseudomonas|s__Pseudomonas_citronellolis     23     23    11
```

out

```
Genus               D1                            D2                           D3
g__Acinetobacter    s__Acinetobacter_pittii       s__Acinetobacter_larvae      s__Acinetobacter_pittii
g__Pseudomonas      s__Pseudomonas_citronellolis  s__Pseudomonas_citronellolis s__Pseudomonas_aeruginosa
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `dplyr` and `tidyr`, assuming your first column is called `V1`. We `separate` the column into two by splitting on `"|"` and then use `summarise_at` to summarise columns which start with `"D"` and select the corresponding `Species` to max value in the column.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  separate(V1, into = c("Genus", "Species"), sep  = "\\|") %>%
  group_by(Genus) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(starts_with("D")), ~Species[which.max(.)])

# A tibble: 2 x 4
#  Genus            D1                           D2                           D3                       
#  <chr>            <chr>                        <chr>                        <chr>                    
#1 g__Acinetobacter s__Acinetobacter_pittii      s__Acinetobacter_larvae      s__Acinetobacter_pittii  
#2 g__Pseudomonas   s__Pseudomonas_citronellolis s__Pseudomonas_citronellolis s__Pseudomonas_aeruginosa
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 5L), .Label = 
c("g__Acinetobacter|s__Acinetobacter_larvae", 
"g__Acinetobacter|s__Acinetobacter_oleivorans", 
"g__Acinetobacter|s__Acinetobacter_pittii", 
"g__Pseudomonas|s__Pseudomonas_aeruginosa", 
"g__Pseudomonas|s__Pseudomonas_citronellolis"
), class = "factor"), D1 = c(12L, 4L, 1L, 13L, 23L), D2 = c(21L, 
4L, 53L, 13L, 23L), D3 = c(424L, 23L, 232L, 323L, 11L)), class = 
"data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```